# vpnc cannot connect to VPN due to vpnc-script

Tags: vpn, vpnc

I am trying to connect establish VPN connection with vpnc but it failed with message

```
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "ipid" is a garbage
```

According to http://blog.nowherelan.com/2011/10/10/vpnc-on-ubuntu-oneiric-error-either-to-is-duplicate-or-ipid-is-a-garbage/ I replaced vpnc-script but got a new error message:

```
/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script: 658: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ";;")
```

After that it starts vpnc-connect "in background" but no IP address is assigned:

ifonfig -a:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          POINTOPOINT NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:531 (531.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

uname -a:

```
Linux mobile 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ideas?

Finally I got working version of vpnc-script here http://git.infradead.org/users/dwmw2/vpnc-scripts.git/blob_plain/4deaaf9a32:/vpnc-script

Comment: Did you try the GUI way using the network manager?

Comment: 2lumbric: yes, it doesn't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vpnc/+bug/805435) was fixed and relased only for Ubuntu Precise and I think you should mark it as affecting you and ask there for a possible solution to the problem in Oneiric (a merge of the released fix in Oneiric or another solution).

Comment: ok, thanks man, you didn't answer the question directly but your answer leads me to a working version of vpnc-script:

Comment: ... which you find in the question, bottom link

Answer (score 0):

i have the work around for the following error :

step 1: see what you need to do is, firstly take the backup of the vpnc script through the below command :

```
sudo cp /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script.bck
```

Step 2: now what you need to do is open the vpnc-script by any editor love to work with(vi, vim , emacs, gedit).

```
sudo gedit /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script
```

and remove the content inside it and copy the content below :

---

```
#!/bin/sh
# List of parameters passed through environment
#* reason                       -- why this script was called, one of: pre-init connect disconnect
#* VPNGATEWAY                   -- vpn gateway address (always present)
#* TUNDEV                       -- tunnel device (always present)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS         -- address (always present)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_MTU             -- mtu (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK         -- netmask (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASKLEN      -- netmask length (often unset)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NETADDR         -- address of network (only present if netmask is set)
#* INTERNAL_IP4_DNS             -- list of dns servers
#* INTERNAL_IP4_NBNS            -- list of wins servers
#* INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS         -- IPv6 address
#* INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK         -- IPv6 netmask
#* INTERNAL_IP6_DNS             -- IPv6 list of dns servers
#* CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN             -- default domain name
#* CISCO_BANNER                 -- banner from server
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC              -- number of networks in split-network-list
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_ADDR      -- network address
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_MASK      -- subnet mask (for example: 255.255.255.0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_MASKLEN   -- subnet masklen (for example: 24)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_PROTOCOL  -- protocol (often just 0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_SPORT     -- source port (often just 0)
#* CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_DPORT     -- destination port (often just 0)
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC         -- number of networks in IPv6 split-network-list
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_%d_ADDR -- IPv6 network address
#* CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_$%d_MASKLEN -- IPv6 subnet masklen

# FIXMEs:

# Section A: route handling

# 1) The 3 values CISCO_SPLIT_INC_%d_PROTOCOL/SPORT/DPORT are currently being ignored
#   In order to use them, we'll probably need os specific solutions
#   * Linux: iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING <conditions> -j ROUTE --oif $TUNDEV
#       This would be an *alternative* to changing the routes (and thus 2) and 3)
#       shouldn't be relevant at all)
# 2) There are two different functions to set routes: generic routes and the
#   default route. Why isn't the defaultroute handled via the generic route case?
# 3) In the split tunnel case, all routes but the default route might get replaced
#   without getting restored later. We should explicitely check and save them just
#   like the defaultroute
# 4) Replies to a dhcp-server should never be sent into the tunnel

# Section B: Split DNS handling

# 1) Maybe dnsmasq can do something like that
# 2) Parse dns packets going out via tunnel and redirect them to original dns-server

#env | sort
#set -x

# =========== script (variable) setup ====================================

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH

OS="`uname -s`"

HOOKS_DIR=/etc/vpnc
DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE=/var/run/vpnc/defaultroute
RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP=/var/run/vpnc/resolv.conf-backup
SCRIPTNAME=`basename $0`

# some systems, eg. Darwin & FreeBSD, prune /var/run on boot
if [ ! -d "/var/run/vpnc" ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/run/vpnc
    [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon /var/run/vpnc
fi

# stupid SunOS: no blubber in /usr/local/bin ... (on stdout)
IPROUTE="`which ip | grep '^/'`" 2> /dev/null

if ifconfig --help 2>&1 | grep BusyBox > /dev/null; then
    ifconfig_syntax_inet=""
else
    ifconfig_syntax_inet="inet"
fi

if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
    ifconfig_syntax_ptp="pointopoint"
    route_syntax_gw="gw"
    route_syntax_del="del"
    route_syntax_netmask="netmask"
else
    ifconfig_syntax_ptp=""
    route_syntax_gw=""
    route_syntax_del="delete"
    route_syntax_netmask="-netmask"
fi
if [ "$OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
    route_syntax_interface="-interface"
    ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6="$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
else
    route_syntax_interface=""
    ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6=""
fi

if [ -r /etc/openwrt_release ] && [ -n "$OPENWRT_INTERFACE" ]; then
        . /etc/functions.sh
    include /lib/network
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_openwrt
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_openwrt
elif [ -x /sbin/resolvconf ]; then # Optional tool on Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_manager
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_manager
elif [ -x /sbin/netconfig ]; then # tool on Suse after 11.1
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_suse_netconfig
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_suse_netconfig
elif [ -x /sbin/modify_resolvconf ]; then # Mandatory tool on Suse earlier than 11.1
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_suse
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_suse
else # Generic for any OS
    MODIFYRESOLVCONF=modify_resolvconf_generic
    RESTORERESOLVCONF=restore_resolvconf_generic
fi


# =========== script hooks =================================================

run_hooks() {
    HOOK="$1"

    if [ -d ${HOOKS_DIR}/${HOOK}.d ]; then
        for script in ${HOOKS_DIR}/${HOOK}.d/* ; do
        [ -f $script ] && . $script
        done
    fi
}

# =========== tunnel interface handling ====================================

do_ifconfig() {
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_MTU" ]; then
        MTU=$INTERNAL_IP4_MTU
    elif [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        MTUDEV=`$IPROUTE route get "$VPNGATEWAY" | sed -ne 's/^.*dev \([a-z0-9]*\).*$/\1/p'`
        MTU=`$IPROUTE link show "$MTUDEV" | sed -ne 's/^.*mtu \([[:digit:]]\+\).*$/\1/p'`
        if [ -n "$MTU" ]; then
            MTU=`expr $MTU - 88`
        fi
    fi

    if [ -z "$MTU" ]; then
        MTU=1412
    fi

    # Point to point interface require a netmask of 255.255.255.255 on some systems
    if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        $IPROUTE link set dev "$TUNDEV" up mtu "$MTU"
        $IPROUTE addr add "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS/255.255.255.255" peer "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" dev "$TUNDEV"
    else
        ifconfig "$TUNDEV" ${ifconfig_syntax_inet} "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $ifconfig_syntax_ptp "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" netmask 255.255.255.255 mtu ${MTU} up
    fi

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK" ]; then
        set_network_route $INTERNAL_IP4_NETADDR $INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK $INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASKLEN
    fi

    # If the netmask is provided, it contains the address _and_ netmask
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ] && [ -z "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" ]; then
        INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK="$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS/128"
    fi
    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" ]; then
        if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
        $IPROUTE -6 addr add $INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK dev $TUNDEV
        else
        # Unlike for Legacy IP, we don't specify the dest_address
        # here on *BSD. OpenBSD for one will refuse to accept
        # incoming packets to that address if we do.
        # OpenVPN does the same (gives dest_address for Legacy IP
        # but not for IPv6).
        # Only Solaris needs it; hence $ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6
            ifconfig "$TUNDEV" inet6 $INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK $ifconfig_syntax_ptpv6 mtu $MTU up
        fi
    fi
}

destroy_tun_device() {
    case "$OS" in
    NetBSD|FreeBSD) # and probably others...
        ifconfig "$TUNDEV" destroy
        ;;
    esac
}

# =========== route handling ====================================

if [ -n "$IPROUTE" ]; then
    fix_ip_get_output () {
        sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | \
            sed -ne '1p;/via/{N;p};/dev/{N;p};/src/{N;p};/mtu/{N;p}'
    }

    set_vpngateway_route() {
        $IPROUTE route add `$IPROUTE route get "$VPNGATEWAY" | fix_ip_get_output`
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    del_vpngateway_route() {
        $IPROUTE route $route_syntax_del "$VPNGATEWAY"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_default_route() {
        $IPROUTE route | grep '^default' | fix_ip_get_output > "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        $IPROUTE route replace default dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        $IPROUTE route replace "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    reset_default_route() {
        if [ -s "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE" ]; then
            $IPROUTE route replace `cat "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"`
            $IPROUTE route flush cache
            rm -f -- "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        fi
    }

    del_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        $IPROUTE route $route_syntax_del "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    set_ipv6_default_route() {
        # We don't save/restore IPv6 default route; just add a higher-priority one.
        $IPROUTE -6 route add default dev "$TUNDEV" metric 1
        $IPROUTE -6 route flush cache
    }

    set_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASKLEN="$2"
        $IPROUTE -6 route replace "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    reset_ipv6_default_route() {
        $IPROUTE -6 route del default dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE route flush cache
    }

    del_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASKLEN="$2"
        $IPROUTE -6 route del "$NETWORK/$NETMASKLEN" dev "$TUNDEV"
        $IPROUTE -6 route flush cache
    }
else # use route command
    get_default_gw() {
        # isn't -n supposed to give --numeric output?
        # apperently not...
        # Get rid of lines containing IPv6 addresses (':')
        netstat -r -n | awk '/:/ { next; } /^(default|0\.0\.0\.0)/ { print $2; }'
    }

    set_vpngateway_route() {
        route add -host "$VPNGATEWAY" $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`"
    }

    del_vpngateway_route() {
        route $route_syntax_del -host "$VPNGATEWAY" $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`"
    }

    set_default_route() {
        DEFAULTGW="`get_default_gw`"
        echo "$DEFAULTGW" > "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        route $route_syntax_del default $route_syntax_gw "$DEFAULTGW"
        route add default $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    set_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        del_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
        route add -net "$NETWORK" $route_syntax_netmask "$NETMASK" $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    reset_default_route() {
        if [ -s "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE" ]; then
            route $route_syntax_del default $route_syntax_gw "`get_default_gw`" $route_syntax_interface
            route add default $route_syntax_gw `cat "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"`
            rm -f -- "$DEFAULT_ROUTE_FILE"
        fi
    }

    del_network_route() {
        case "$OS" in
        Linux|NetBSD|Darwin|SunOS) # and probably others...
            # routes are deleted automatically on device shutdown
            return
            ;;
        esac
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        NETMASKLEN="$3"
        route $route_syntax_del -net "$NETWORK" $route_syntax_netmask "$NETMASK" $route_syntax_gw "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS"
    }

    set_ipv6_default_route() {
        route add -inet6 default "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
    }

    set_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        route add -inet6 -net "$NETWORK/$NETMASK" "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" $route_syntax_interface
        :
    }

    reset_ipv6_default_route() {
        route $route_syntax_del -inet6 default "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
        :
    }

    del_ipv6_network_route() {
        NETWORK="$1"
        NETMASK="$2"
        route $route_syntax_del -inet6 "$NETWORK/$NETMASK" "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS"
        :
    }

fi

# =========== resolv.conf handling ====================================

# =========== resolv.conf handling for any OS =========================

modify_resolvconf_generic() {
    grep '^#@VPNC_GENERATED@' /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 || cp -- /etc/resolv.conf "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"
    NEW_RESOLVCONF="#@VPNC_GENERATED@ -- this file is generated by vpnc
# and will be overwritten by vpnc
# as long as the above mark is intact"

    # Remember the original value of CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN we need it later
    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG="$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    # Don't step on INTERNAL_IP4_DNS value, use a temporary variable
    INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP="$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS"
    exec 6< "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"
    while read LINE <&6 ; do
        case "$LINE" in
            nameserver*)
                if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP" ]; then
                    read ONE_NAMESERVER INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP <<-EOF
    $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP
EOF
                    LINE="nameserver $ONE_NAMESERVER"
                else
                    LINE=""
                fi
                ;;
            search*)
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
                    LINE="$LINE $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
                    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN=""
                fi
                ;;
            domain*)
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
                    LINE="domain $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
                    CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN=""
                fi
                ;;
        esac
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
$LINE"
    done
    exec 6<&-

    for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS_TEMP ; do
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
nameserver $i"
    done
    if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
search $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    fi
    echo "$NEW_RESOLVCONF" > /etc/resolv.conf

    if [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        case "`uname -r`" in
            # Skip for pre-10.4 systems
            4.*|5.*|6.*|7.*)
                ;;
            # 10.4 and later require use of scutil for DNS to work properly
            *)
                OVERRIDE_PRIMARY=""
                if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
                    if [ $CISCO_SPLIT_INC -lt 1 ]; then
                        # Must override for correct default route
                        # Cannot use multiple DNS matching in this case
                        OVERRIDE_PRIMARY='d.add OverridePrimary # 1'
                    fi
                fi
                # Uncomment the following if/fi pair to use multiple
                # DNS matching when available.  When multiple DNS matching
                # is present, anything reading the /etc/resolv.conf file
                # directly will probably not work as intended.
                #if [ -z "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG" ]; then
                    # Cannot use multiple DNS matching without a domain
                    OVERRIDE_PRIMARY='d.add OverridePrimary # 1'
                #fi
                scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                    open
                    d.init
                    d.add ServerAddresses * $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS
                    set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                    d.init
                    # next line overrides the default gateway and breaks split routing
                    # d.add Router $INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS
                    d.add Addresses * $INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS
                    d.add SubnetMasks * 255.255.255.255
                    d.add InterfaceName $TUNDEV
                    $OVERRIDE_PRIMARY
                    set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/IPv4
                    close
                EOF
                if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG" ]; then
                    scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                        open
                        get State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                        d.add DomainName $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        d.add SearchDomains * $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        d.add SupplementalMatchDomains * $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN_ORIG
                        set State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                        close
                    EOF
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}

restore_resolvconf_generic() {
    if [ ! -f "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP" ]; then
        return
    fi
    grep '^#@VPNC_GENERATED@' /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP" > /etc/resolv.conf
    rm -f -- "$RESOLV_CONF_BACKUP"

    if [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        case "`uname -r`" in
            # Skip for pre-10.4 systems
            4.*|5.*|6.*|7.*)
                ;;
            # 10.4 and later require use of scutil for DNS to work properly
            *)
                scutil >/dev/null 2>&1 <<-EOF
                    open
                    remove State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/IPv4
                    remove State:/Network/Service/$TUNDEV/DNS
                    close
                EOF
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}
# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/netconfig (Suse 11.1) =====================

# Suse provides a script that modifies resolv.conf. Use it because it will
# restart/reload all other services that care about it (e.g. lwresd).  [unclear if this is still true, but probably --mlk]

modify_resolvconf_suse_netconfig()
{
    /sbin/netconfig modify -s vpnc -i "$TUNDEV" <<-EOF
        INTERFACE='$TUNDEV'
        DNSSERVERS='$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS'
        DNSDOMAIN='$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN'
        EOF
}
# Restore resolv.conf to old contents on Suse
restore_resolvconf_suse_netconfig()
{
    /sbin/netconfig remove -s vpnc -i "$TUNDEV"
}

# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/modify_resolvconf (Suse) =====================

# Suse provides a script that modifies resolv.conf. Use it because it will
# restart/reload all other services that care about it (e.g. lwresd).

modify_resolvconf_suse()
{
    FULL_SCRIPTNAME=`readlink -f $0`
    RESOLV_OPTS=''
    test -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" && RESOLV_OPTS="-n \"$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS\""
    test -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" && RESOLV_OPTS="$RESOLV_OPTS -d $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    test -n "$RESOLV_OPTS" && eval /sbin/modify_resolvconf modify -s vpnc -p $SCRIPTNAME -f $FULL_SCRIPTNAME -e $TUNDEV $RESOLV_OPTS -t \"This file was created by $SCRIPTNAME\"
}

# Restore resolv.conf to old contents on Suse
restore_resolvconf_suse()
{
    FULL_SCRIPTNAME=`readlink -f $0`
    /sbin/modify_resolvconf restore -s vpnc -p $SCRIPTNAME -f $FULL_SCRIPTNAME -e $TUNDEV
}

# === resolv.conf handling via UCI (OpenWRT) =========

modify_resolvconf_openwrt() {
    add_dns $OPENWRT_INTERFACE $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS
}

restore_resolvconf_openwrt() {
    remove_dns $OPENWRT_INTERFACE
}
# === resolv.conf handling via /sbin/resolvconf (Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo)) =========

modify_resolvconf_manager() {
    NEW_RESOLVCONF=""
    for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS; do
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
nameserver $i"
    done
    if [ -n "$CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN" ]; then
        NEW_RESOLVCONF="$NEW_RESOLVCONF
domain $CISCO_DEF_DOMAIN"
    fi
    echo "$NEW_RESOLVCONF" | /sbin/resolvconf -a $TUNDEV
}

restore_resolvconf_manager() {
    /sbin/resolvconf -d $TUNDEV
}

# ========= Toplevel state handling  =======================================

kernel_is_2_6_or_above() {
    case `uname -r` in
        1.*|2.[012345]*)
            return 1
            ;;
        *)
            return 0
            ;;
    esac
}

do_pre_init() {
    if [ "$OS" = "Linux" ]; then
        if (exec 6<> /dev/net/tun) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
            :
        else # can't open /dev/net/tun
            test -e /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe && `cat /proc/sys/kernel/modprobe` tun 2>/dev/null
            # fix for broken devfs in kernel 2.6.x
            if [ "`readlink /dev/net/tun`" = misc/net/tun \
                -a ! -e /dev/net/misc/net/tun -a -e /dev/misc/net/tun ] ; then
                ln -sf /dev/misc/net/tun /dev/net/tun
            fi
            # make sure tun device exists
            if [ ! -e /dev/net/tun ]; then
                mkdir -p /dev/net
                mknod -m 0640 /dev/net/tun c 10 200
                [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && /sbin/restorecon /dev/net/tun
            fi
            # workaround for a possible latency caused by udev, sleep max. 10s
            if kernel_is_2_6_or_above ; then
                for x in `seq 100` ; do
                    (exec 6<> /dev/net/tun) > /dev/null 2>&1 && break;
                    sleep 0.1
                done
            fi
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "FreeBSD" ]; then
        if [ ! -e /dev/tun ]; then
            kldload if_tun
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "GNU/kFreeBSD" ]; then
        if [ ! -e /dev/tun ]; then
            kldload if_tun
        fi
    elif [ "$OS" = "NetBSD" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "OpenBSD" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "SunOS" ]; then
        :
    elif [ "$OS" = "Darwin" ]; then
        :
    fi
}

do_connect() {
    if [ -n "$CISCO_BANNER" ]; then
        echo "Connect Banner:"
        echo "$CISCO_BANNER" | while read LINE ; do echo "|" "$LINE" ; done
        echo
    fi

    set_vpngateway_route
    do_ifconfig
    if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASK}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETWORK != "0.0.0.0" ]; then
                set_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                set_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            echo "$i" | grep : >/dev/null || \
                set_network_route "$i" "255.255.255.255" "32"
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_ADDRESS" ]; then
        set_default_route
    fi
    if [ -n "$CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETMASKLEN -lt 128 ]; then
                set_ipv6_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                set_ipv6_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            if echo "$i" | grep : >/dev/null; then
                set_ipv6_network_route "$i" "128"
            fi
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" -o -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ]; then
        set_ipv6_default_route
    fi

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" ]; then
        $MODIFYRESOLVCONF
    fi
}

do_disconnect() {
    if [ -n "$CISCO_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASK="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASK}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETWORK != "0.0.0.0" ]; then
                # FIXME: This doesn't restore previously overwritten
                #        routes.
                del_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            else
                reset_default_route
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP4_DNS ; do
            del_network_route "$i" "255.255.255.255" "32"
        done
    else
        reset_default_route
    fi
    if [ -n "$CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC" ]; then
        i=0
        while [ $i -lt $CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC ] ; do
            eval NETWORK="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_ADDR}"
            eval NETMASKLEN="\${CISCO_IPV6_SPLIT_INC_${i}_MASKLEN}"
            if [ $NETMASKLEN -eq 0 ]; then
                reset_ipv6_default_route
            else
                del_ipv6_network_route "$NETWORK" "$NETMASKLEN"
            fi
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
        for i in $INTERNAL_IP6_DNS ; do
            del_ipv6_network_route "$i" "128"
        done
    elif [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_NETMASK" -o -n "$INTERNAL_IP6_ADDRESS" ]; then
        reset_ipv6_default_route
    fi

    del_vpngateway_route

    if [ -n "$INTERNAL_IP4_DNS" ]; then
        $RESTORERESOLVCONF
    fi
    destroy_tun_device
}

#### Main

if [ -z "$reason" ]; then
    echo "this script must be called from vpnc" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

case "$reason" in
    pre-init)
        run_hooks pre-init
        do_pre_init
        ;;
    connect)
        run_hooks connect
        do_connect
        run_hooks post-connect
        ;;
    disconnect)
        run_hooks disconnect
        do_disconnect
        run_hooks post-disconnect
        ;;
    reconnect)
        run_hooks reconnect
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown reason '$reason'. Maybe vpnc-script is out of date" 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
****************************************************************************************
```

save and close the vpnc-script file.

Step 3: run the vpnc now, you want get the ipid error now.

Note: see if you replace the vpnc-script file as done in above example you will get error because it change the flag set onto the file. So, we just only need to change is the content of the vpnc-script file.

Cheers!!

-Simranjeet

Comment: use the script from the answer (bottom link) rather than this one

Answer (score 0):

This issue exists in Ubuntu 20 upgraded from 18. Remove the first line which is commented in the file /etc/resolv.conf file.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have systemd-resolved and this does not make any sense to me.